# Ansible: is it possible to use template to create files but copy it to local host to another remote host?

Tags: ansible

From ansible documentations and examples for [template](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html), the templates help us to create customized compile files and copy it to the corresponding server. Is it possible to use them to create this customized files but instead copy them to another remote server, or localhost? for example

```
-hosts: customhosts    
- template:
        src: /mytemplates/foo.j2
        dest: /etc/file.conf
```

it creates custom foo.j2 files for each of the nodes in customhosts group, but it copies each file to the corresponding server. How can we make it copy all these files to the 'remote-host' sever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use them to create this customized files but instead copy them to another remote server, or localhost?

make a play towards localhost, with a loop that uses the template module, and with_items: the group of hosts you want to process. obviously `dest` should be a name that includes the hostnames (or you can come up with another plan to make the filenames unique per host) so that you dont overwrite the produced file on each loop.

> How can we make it copy all these files to the 'remote-host' sever?

then, on a second play towards the 'remote-host' server, you will make a loop to send those files one by one (if in understood correctly what you want to achieve)